# Firestore Concurrent Transactions Freezing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I am having an issue where Firestore transactions freeze when run concurrently. As background, I have a Firestore collection, where each document has a dollar amount and a time. I am creating a function that releases a desired dollar amount from this collection, starting with the oldest documents.

For example, a function call to release $150 will iterate through the collection, removing dollar amounts from the collection until a total of $150 is removed. I do this using a recursive function which 1) finds the oldest dollar amount, 2) removes the inputted amount (i.e. $150) from that number, or deletes the number if the inputted amount is greater than the number, and 3) recurs if there is still a remaining amount to be removed. I use a Firestore transaction for step (2), as there is the possibility this collection will be changed by multiple users at the same time (and note that if I combine (1) and (2) to include the query in the transaction, the code behavior is unchanged).

The code below updates the collection correctly. However, it takes an extremely long time if it is called while an earlier instance is already running: if I call it once, then call it again before the first call is completed, it freezes and has potential to take 20-30 minutes instead of the usual 1-5 seconds. While it is clear that contention between concurrent transactions is causing the freezing (when I remove the write portion of the transaction, there is no freezing), the unknown question is what specifically about the contention is causing the freezing and how to fix it.

**Addition**: it seems this freezing may be related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2452. Consistent with that post, I am facing a 30 second freeze per transaction, which becomes many minutes given a single release has multiple transactions.

```
 function releaseAmountFromStack(amount) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let db = admin.firestore();
    let stackRef = db.collection("stack");

    stackRef.orderBy("expirationTime", "asc").limit(1)
      .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        if(querySnapshot.empty) {
          return reject("None left in stack");
        }

        let itemToRelease = querySnapshot.docs[0];

        releaseItem(itemToRelease.ref, amount)
        .then((actualReleaseAmount) => {
          // If there is still more to release, trigger the next recursion
          // If the full amount has been released, return it
          if (amount > actualReleaseAmount) {
            releaseAmountFromStack(amount-actualReleaseAmount)
            .then((nextActualReleaseAmount) => {
              return resolve(actualReleaseAmount + nextActualReleaseAmount);
            })
            .catch(() => {
              return resolve(actualReleaseAmount);
            });
          } else {
            return resolve(actualReleaseAmount);
          }
        });
    });
  });
}

function releaseItem(itemRef, amountToRelease) {
  let db = admin.firestore();
  return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    return transaction.get(itemRef).then((itemDoc) => {
      let itemAmount = itemDoc.data().amount;
      let actualReleaseAmount = Math.min(amountToRelease, itemAmount);

      // If item is exhausted, delete it. Else, update amount
      if (actualReleaseAmount >= itemAmount) {
        transaction.delete(itemDoc.ref);
      } else {
        transaction.set(itemDoc.ref, {
          amount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1*Number(actualReleaseAmount)),
        }, {merge: true});
      }
      return actualReleaseAmount;
      });
  });
}
```

Here are some useful facts from the debug process so far. Thank you so much.

- During the freeze, it does not trigger a breakpoint on any of these lines of code. Only when the freeze finishes is a breakpoint triggered. This indicates the delay is not caused by looping through my code (if it were, a breakpoint should be triggered)
- The function eventually works as intended in that it releases the correct amount, it just takes a very long time. It will generally freeze, then execute, then freeze, then execute, and so forth until the process is completed
- Firestore usage stats show the function executes hundreds of reads and writes, even if it only needs to (and I would expect) it to iterate a few dozen times to release the requisite amount from the collection

Comment: The code might produce a race condition.

Comment: Thank you. Which aspect do you think causes a race condition? From my testing, it seems the logic works, it is just a matter of each transaction taking 30 seconds for unclear reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what caused the elusive freezing. I noticed that the freezing of each transaction was consistently 30 seconds, which prompted me to search for discussion on 30 second transaction freezes. I found (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2452) which indicates this is an issue with how the Firebase emulator handles concurrent transactions. Indeed, when I deploy the code instead of using the emulator, the freezing is no longer there!

TLDR: the Firebase emulator has an unnatural delay with concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's fix your `releaseAmountFromStack` function so that you aren't using a Promise constructor for a Promise-returning API (known as the [Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/3068190)). If either your `stackRef` query or `releaseItem` function throw an error, your code would encounter an `UnhandledPromiseRejection` because neither Promise chain has a `catch` handler.

```
function releaseAmountFromStack(amount) {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const stackRef = db.collection("stack");

  return stackRef
    .orderBy("expirationTime", "asc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      if(querySnapshot.empty) {
        return Promise.reject("Out of stock");
      }

      const itemToRelease = querySnapshot.docs[0];

      return releaseItem(itemToRelease.ref, amount);
    })
    .then((releasedAmount) => {
       const amountLeft = amount - releasedAmount;

       if (amountLeft <= 0)
         return releasedAmount;

       return releaseAmountFromStack(amountLeft)
         .then((nextReleasedAmount) => nextReleasedAmount + releasedAmount)
         .catch((err) => {
           if (err === "Out of stock") {
             return releasedAmount;
           } else {
             // rethrow unexpected errors
             throw err;
           }
         });
     });
}
```

Because that function involves nested Promise chains, switching to an `async`/`await` syntax can flatten it out to:

```
async function releaseAmountFromStack(amount) {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const stackRef = db.collection("stack");

  const querySnapshot = await stackRef
    .orderBy("expirationTime", "asc")
    .limit(1)
    .get();
  
  if (querySnapshot.empty)
    return 0; // out of stock

  const itemToRelease = querySnapshot.docs[0];

  const releasedAmount = await releaseItem(itemToRelease.ref, amount);

  const amountLeft = amount - releasedAmount;
  
  if (amountLeft <= 0) {
    // nothing left to release, return released amount
    return releasedAmount; 
  }

  // If here, there is more to release, trigger the next recursion
  const nextReleasedAmount = await releaseAmountFromStack(amountLeft);

  return nextReleasedAmount + releasedAmount;
}
```

**Note:** In the above flattened version, we don't need to handle catch because we can just return 0 instead. This means any irrelevant errors will be thrown normally.

Next we can move on to `releaseItem`, which is the actual cause of your problem. Here, you aren't handling the case where another instance is deleting the item you are reading, you just assume that it exists and then end up dealing with `NaN` and/or negative balances. As **an example** of what ends up happening, you can end up with the following sequence of events (it's more complex than this because you are using `FieldValue.increment()` - add in a Server Client doing transactions too):

```
 Client A                      Server                      Client B
Release 50                                                Release 80
    ┌┐         Get Doc #1        ┌┐                           ┌┐
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││      Doc #1 Snapshot      ││         Get Doc #1        ││
    ││       { amount: 10 }      ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││      Doc #1 Snapshot      ││
    ││                           ││       { amount: 10 }      ││
    ││   Result: Delete Doc #1   ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││          ACCEPTED         ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││   Result: Delete Doc #1   ││
    ││         Get Doc #2        ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││         REJECTED          ││
    ││                           ││    New Doc #1 Snapshot    ││
    ││                           ││          <null>           ││
    ││      Doc #2 Snapshot      ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││      { amount: 15 }       ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││ Result: Set Doc #1 to -10 ││
    ││                           ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││   Result: Delete Doc #2   ││             ▲             ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││             │             ││
    ││          ACCEPTED         ││           ERROR           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    └┘                           └┘                           └┘
```

Because you are using a transaction, you already know the current value for `amount` so you can just do the calculation on the client and write the new amount instead of using `FieldValue.increment()`. That operator is better suited for doing simple updates of a value where you don't need to know the current value.

```
function releaseItem(itemRef, amountToRelease) {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    return transaction.get(itemRef).then((itemDoc) => {
      if (!itemDoc.exists) {
        // target has been deleted, do nothing & return
        // amount that was released (0)
        return 0;
      }
  
      const itemAmount = itemDoc.get("amount");
      const actualReleaseAmount = Math.min(amountToRelease, itemAmount);

      if (actualReleaseAmount >= itemAmount) {
        // exhausted supply. delete item
        transaction.delete(itemDoc.ref);
      } else {
        // have leftover supply. update amount
        transaction.set(itemDoc.ref, {
          amount: itemAmount - actualReleaseAmount, 
        }, {merge: true});
      }

      // return amount that was released
      return actualReleaseAmount;
    });
  });
}
```

This won't solve your issue completely as you still have a data contention problem if two or more clients try to take items off the same stack at the same time. As **an example** of this, see the following event flow (yet again timing will be a major factor in how things play out):

```
 Client A                      Server                      Client B
Release 50                                                Release 80
    ┌┐         Get Doc #1        ┌┐                           ┌┐
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││      Doc #1 Snapshot      ││         Get Doc #1        ││
    ││       { amount: 10 }      ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││      Doc #1 Snapshot      ││
    ││                           ││       { amount: 10 }      ││
    ││   Result: Delete Doc #1   ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││          ACCEPTED         ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││   Result: Delete Doc #1   ││
    ││         Get Doc #2        ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││         REJECTED          ││
    ││                           ││    New Doc #1 Snapshot    ││
    ││                           ││          <null>           ││
    ││      Doc #2 Snapshot      ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││      { amount: 15 }       ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││     Result: Cancelled     ││
    ││                           ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││   Result: Delete Doc #2   ││         Get Doc #2        ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││          ACCEPTED         ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││      Doc #2 Snapshot      ││
    ││         Get Doc #3        ││          <null>           ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││     Result: Cancelled     ││
    ││                           ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││      Doc #3 Snapshot      ││                           ││
    ││      { amount: 10 }       ││                           ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││         Get Doc #3        ││
    ││                           ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││                           ││                           ││
    ││   Result: Delete Doc #3   ││      Doc #3 Snapshot      ││
    ││     ────────────────►     ││          <null>           ││
    ││          ACCEPTED         ││     ────────────────►     ││
    ││     ◄────────────────     ││                           ││
    ││                           ││     Result: Cancelled     ││
    ││         Get Doc #4        ││     ◄────────────────     ││
    └┘     ────────────────►     └┘                           └┘
```

One way around this would be to pull down multiple items at a time, consume them as appropriate and write the changes back, all in a transaction. Yet again, not dealing with the problem, just making it less likely that clients will fight over the same documents over and over again.

```
async function releaseAmountFromStack(amount) {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const stackQuery = db
    .collection("stack")
    .orderBy("expirationTime", "asc")
    .limit(1);

  const releasedAmount = await _releaseAmountFromStack(stackQuery, amount);

  const amountLeft = amount - releasedAmount;

  if (amountLeft <= 0) {
    // nothing left to release, return released amount
    return releasedAmount; 
  }

  // If here, there is more to release, trigger the next recursion
  const nextReleasedAmount = await releaseAmountFromStack(amountLeft)
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err !== "Empty stack") throw err;
      return 0;
    });

  return nextReleasedAmount + releasedAmount;
}

function _releaseAmountFromStack(query, amountToRelease) => {
  return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    return transaction.get(query).then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        // nothing in stack, return released amount (0)
        return Promise.reject("Empty stack");
      }

      let remainingAmountToRelease = amountToRelease;

      for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
        const itemAmount = doc.get("amount");
        const amountChange = Math.min(itemAmount, remainingAmountToRelease);

        if (amountChange >= itemAmount) {
          transaction.delete(doc.ref);
        } else {
          remainingAmountToRelease -= amountChange;
          transaction.set(doc.ref, {
            amount: itemAmount - amountChange
          }, { merge: true });
        }

        if (remainingAmountToRelease <= 0) break; // stop iterating early
      }
  
      // return amount that was released
      return /* totalAmountReleased = */ amountToRelease - remainingAmountToRelease;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sam for the thorough response. However, after I've made the changes you mentioned, while this does make the code style cleaner it does not impact the contention freezing. As you lay out there is contention, but it is still not clear to me why this contention is causing freezing - as your example shows it will execute correctly, just after some contention (and this is consistent with my logs as well - it executes as intended, but takes several minutes, and it is not clear what could be driving such a long runtime). Do you have a sense what might be causing the underlying issue?